# URL with spaces in CURL and PHP

Tags: php, curl

I have the following url, but I can't get it working with the spaces. The spaces are in $url2. How can I get the filter in the URL working? Now the filter is ignored. This means I receive all the customers instead of only the client with the specific emailaddress.

```
$url1 = "https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/v2.0/".$tenant."/Prod/ODataV4/Company('Cronus_Test')/CMS_Klant?$";
$url2 = "filter=E_Mail eq '".$row['emailadres']."'";

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => "".$url1."",
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
            CURLOPT_GETFIELDS => "".$url2."",
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                "Authorization: Bearer ".$token.""
            ),
        ));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: Why does your `$url1` contain a `$` at the end?

Comment: I can't even find `CURLOPT_GETFIELDS` mentioned in the PHP documentation for either curl_setopt or curl_setopt_array, not sure what's up with that. I'd use `http_build_query`, and append the result as query string to the first URL directly.

Answer (score 0):

You've got to url-encode your url.

In your case the space is %20

But better use urlencode() : https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

```
CURLOPT_GETFIELDS => urlencode($url2),
```

Comment: Thanks. When I use urlencode I receive an Internal Server Error.

Comment: @Matthijs `Internal Server Error` is a generic client side error message. You need to check the server's error logs to see what the error is.

Comment: @Loïc Still the same. The filter doesn't work.